# Unable to emulate browser POST requests without getting a Response [500]. Why?

Tags: python, python-requests

```py
import requests

url = 'https://cmoffice.kenes.com/cmsearchableprogrammev15/conferencemanager/CM_W3_SearchableProgram/api/persionid/anonymous/type/normal/getfilteredsessions/conference/igcs19'

headers = {'accept': '*/*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.471841928.1549896884; _gid=GA1.2.1479150813.1563120868; __RequestVerificationToken_L2NtU2VhcmNoYWJsZVByb2dyYW1tZVYxNQ2=t57HyXHVNBIm0HZ33v1WyG8hRa4j4RlDEOvFtEfPakPgH5AutBjAN5pSRHnBx_BpBhbMnH6R-tIhSdop_VMtLF-aY7XcXTRFt7vg5X46zgE1; _gat=1',
'origin': 'https://cmoffice.kenes.com',
'referer': 'https://cmoffice.kenes.com/cmsearchableprogrammeV15/conferencemanager/programme/personid/anonymous/igcs19/normal/b833d15f547f3cf698a5e922754684fa334885ed',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

response = requests.post(url, headers = headers)

print(response)
```

Gives Response [500]

However browser is able to get a json response with status_code 200

Can anyone shed some light why and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need a body in your request?

Comment: How are you doing a POST from a browser without first doing a GET?

Comment: Your browser will only ever GET if it just hits that URL.  To POST, it has to send a form.  This likely means that the error lies on the side of the server you're interacting with, not your code; 5xx errors are a class of error which represent server failure, not client failure.

Comment: Why are you bothering to create a requests session if you never use it?

Comment: You request might be getting rejected because of a mismatched CSRF token `__RequestVerificationToken_L2NtU2VhcmNoYWJsZVByb2dyYW1tZVYxNQ2`. Try sending a GET request to `'https://cmoffice.kenes.com/cmsearchableprogrammeV15/conferencemanager/programme/personid/anonymous/igcs19/normal/b833d15f547f3cf698a5e922754684fa334885ed` using the session object first

Comment: GET request to referer 'https://cmoffice.kenes.com/cmsearchableprogrammeV15/conferencemanager/programme/personid/anonymous/igcs19/normal/b833d15f547f3cf698a5e922754684fa334885ed' gives 200 as expected. Problem is only with POST request above.

I suppose error is on server side. Only option seems to manually copy the json response from the browser instead of code getting it for you

Answer (score 0):

Something appears not to be right in the backend. It returns a 500 when you try to post to it, which could be actually anything like for example missing configuration or programming errors.

If I hit the given URL in a browser I get actually a 405 'method not allowed' error.

Comment: "If I hit the given URL in a browser I get actually a 405 'method not allowed' error. " because it only accepts POST requests.